# php- trying to have a text that can have 2 hyperlinks

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a text that says "My Account" when a session is valid. When the user has already logged in, it should redirect them to `AccountPage.html`. If the user has not already logged in, it should redirect them to `AccountLogin.html` instead. I thought I could just add if statements like below but every time it runs to goes straight to `login.html`

```
<a <?php 
if (empty($_SESSION["UserName"])) {
header("location:AccountLogin.html");
}
else {
header("location:AccountPage");
}?>> My Account </a>
```

Comment: You should add session_start(); on top of your PHP script pages to keep sessions alive. EG: <?php session_start(); ... ?> End ye.. that code makes no sense at all..

Comment: Your code does not do anything useful. You clearly do not know the basics of php. if you want to output something, use `echo`. `header()` does NOT do, what you want!

Comment: @icecub and Felk i thought it wouldnt make sense  ive only have about 12 hours of learning php, so very new, i used to use a link label but dont think it will work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should study more. What you want is this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$url = empty($_SESSION['UserName']) ? 'AccountLogin.html' : 'AccountPage';
?>
<a href="<?php echo $url ?>">My Account</a>
```

I highly discourage this kind of code where you mix HTML with PHP, the better would be to use some nice template engine like Smarty, Twig, Mustache, etc... You should study them too.

Bonus: `location` is a function that change the headers sent and instruct the browser to redirect to the specified url, hence it should be used when you need an hard redirect (and should be followed by an `exit` )

Comment: well look at the skill level of the author. you are talking a foreign language to him ;)

Comment: you're right, but I clearly remember the first time I see a piece of code: I didn't understand a thing! xD So it's just how it should be, I think, and some advice on how do things in a better way should not harm :P

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you're looking for. Ofcouse I can't be sure you're setting up the session somewhere the way you should. But if you do, this will work.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['UserName']) || empty($_SESSION['UserName'])){
    //Personally I believe header("location") should only be used for hard urls but ok
    header("location: AccountLogin.html");
} else {
    header("location: AccountPage.html");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting up the link wrong.

Try this:

```
 <?php
if (empty($_SESSION["UserName"])) {
$url = "AccountLogin.html";
}
else {
$url = "AccountPage.html";
}

?>

<a href="<? echo $url ?>">My Account </a>
```